# Is it possible to use the dependent variable within an interaction term? Does this cause any problems?

Tags: r, statistics, interaction

So I am running a regression in which my hypotheses states that the dependent variable influences the effect of the independent variable on the dependent variable, if that makes any sense. In essence the as the dependent variable increases I expect the beta of the independent variable to decrease.
I wanted to solve this by using an interaction term.

y = b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b3*x2*y.

Does this cause any problems. Is this statistically viable? I cannot find any information on this, but I wasn't sure if i am supposed to do this since now my b2 changes from significantly positive to significantly negative which seems strange. b3 is significantly positive btw.

Just for some extra clarification. My dataset consist of the the number of mobile application downloads (DV), the average rating (IV) and the number of ratings (IV). Now the hypothesis is that less popular applications require more information because popularity is an indication of quality to the consumer. That is why I would like to include an interaction between the popularity and the rating variables. To me the best measure of popularity seems the number of downloads of course.

My code, performed in r, for the regression is as follows:

```
an_5 <- lm(new_Install ~ Rating + Reviews + Reviews:new_Install + Rating:new_Install, data=Data_1)
summary(an_5)
```

Expected results would be all 4 to be significant but the last two to be negative and the first two to be positive however the opposite is the case which seems strange. I will gladly provide more information.

Comment: Seems like a better question for [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) but it is not viable to use your dependent variable to predict your dependent variable. A significant interaction indicates that the influence one predictor depends on the level of another predictor. If your `new_Install` depends on the level of `Reviews` or `Rating` then it should be captured by just including the predictors in the model. It sounds like (I am guessing) you may not expect a *linear* relationship between your DV and your IVs, and you can test for that without an interaction with your DV.

Comment: Thanks for the help Andrew. I didn't know about stack exchange. How do you suggest I should test for whether I have a non-linear relationship between my DV and IV?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a statistically viable approach. You are basically just using your independent variable as a distortion for
the actual dependent variable effectively leaking information that is never supposed to be part of the predictors.

From your statement "In essence the as the dependent variable increases I expect the beta of the independent variable to decrease"
I conclude that you would like the variable `x2` to have a lower marginal influence on the dependent variable as the dependent variable
becomes larger. You can achieve something conceptually similar by transforming the independent variables appropriately. For example, assuming x2 has a positive coefficient, the log transformation `+ log_reviews` (where log_reviews = log(reviews)) would mimic a variable with diminishing marginal positive effect.

Comment: Thanks Agrei. I will look into log transformation instead. How can I find out whether I should use log(reviews), just reviews or exp(Reviews) etc?

Comment: There is no general rule. If there is reason to believe the effect decreases as values become larger, a log or sqrt transformation might work, if the opposite is true then squaring / exp might work. Ideas for variables/transformations/interactions can be derived from knowledge about the data generating process or data analysis. From a scientific point of view you should form your hypotheses on something other than the data you are using to evaluate your model, however in practice this may be difficult. It might make sense to visualize your data, form your hypotheses and test on a holdout set.

Comment: thank you. I checked for linearity assumptions and these improved when i used, log(new_Install) and log(reviews)